# input size error while doing neural network programming by MATLAB

Tags: matlab, debugging, neural-network

This is my code:

```
p = input1;
t1 = output1;
net = feedforwardnet(10, 'trainrp');
net.trainParam.epochs = 1000;
net.trainParam.goal = 0.0005;
net = train(net, p, t1);
y1 = sim(net, p);
p = input2;
t2 = tar;
y2 = sim(net, p);
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must match each other.

Error in nnMATLAB.pc (line 24)
  pi = bsxfun(@minus,pi,settings.xoffset);

Error in nncalc.preCalcData (line 20)
data.Pc = calcMode.pc(net,data.X,data.Xi,data.Q,data.TS,calcHints);

Error in nncalc.setup1 (line 118)
calcData = nncalc.preCalcData(matlabMode,matlabHints,net,data,doPc,doPd,calcHints.doFlattenTime);

Error in network/sim (line 283)
[calcMode,calcNet,calcData,calcHints,~,resourceText] = nncalc.setup1(calcMode,net,data);
```

---

I want to make a neural network which has `input1` (for input layer, `310 x 24` matrix) and `output1` (for output layer, `155 x 24` matrix).

After this process, I am going to train my network with these matrices.

Finally, I want to get a simulation result made by this network with `input2` (for input layer,  `31 x 24` matrix).

In summary, I want to train my own network with `input1` and `output1`, and I want to get my simulation result (which is done by above network) with `input2`.

I think these errors are based on input size difference (between `input1` and `input2`)

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just looking breifly at the docs: http://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/train.html my gues would be that you should be trying `train(net, p', t1')`. See if that help at all

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply Dan.

However, I couldn't solve my problem even though I read the docs.

What does train(net, p', t1') mean?

Comment: It cause brand-new error 

Error using network/train (line 272)
Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples.